# how to combine labels with buttons in bootstrap navigation

Tags: css

I'm new to using the Bootstrap CSS framework.  I'm trying to create navigation at the top of the page.  I'm using the navbar collaspe collaspe command, but the link buttons are separated below the labels.  So when I click on the labels I don't go to the page but when I click the button below the labels, I'm sent to the page.  My code is below:

```
    <body class="text-center">
    <nav class="navbar collasped collasped">
          <div class="text-center">
          <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    </div>
    <img class="navbar-left" alt="logo" src="Grandmaster_Hong_Logo.png">

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
    <li>Home <a href="HomePage.html"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only"></span></button></a></li>
    <li>Events <a href="Events.html"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only"></span></button></a></li>
    <li>Photos <a href="Photos.html"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only"></span></button></a></li>
    <li class="active">Videos <a href="Videos.html"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only"></span></button></a></li>
    <li>About Us <a href="About_Us.html"><button type="button" class="navbar-        `   enter code here`toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only"></span></button></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>here
```

Is there a way I can combine these so that when someone clicks on the labels the button is behind it and will take the user to the page?  Is there a certain bootstrap command I should be using?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not use a tag instead of button?

Comment: please use 'collapsed' instead of 'collasped'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misspelled it here.  i used collapsed in the code.  It's still separated out.  Would using a tag instead of a button put them together?  If so, how would I do that in Bootstrap?  I'm new to Bootstrap.  I'm being forced to use it for a final project as a requirement.  Frankly, if it was up to me, I'd create my own responsive CSS since it works better.  Thanks for your help.